# Arcpy UpdateCursor 'SHAPE@X', 'SHAPE@Y' in decimal degrees

Tags: arcpy, units

I have the code below that works, however I want the units to be in decimal degrees. How do I force this?

```
fields2 = ['cent_lat', 'cent_long', 'SHAPE@X', 'SHAPE@Y']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fields2) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = row[2]
        row[1] = row[3]

        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just project the geometry of the point on the fly like the below example which will project a point to WGS 1984 (WKID 4326).  Then you can just get the x and y values from that newly projected point geometry.

What your code might look like:

```
import arcpy

fields2 = ['cent_lat', 'cent_long', 'SHAPE@']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fields2) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        pt = row[2].projectAs('4326').centroid
        row[0] = pt.Y
        row[1] = pt.X

        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

projectAs is a method of the ["pointGeometry"](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/pointgeometry.htm) arcpy class.

Comment: I forgot the quotes around the spatial reference number '4326'

Answer (score 2):

Try that way:

```
fields2 = ['cent_lat', 'cent_long', 'SHAPE@X', 'SHAPE@Y']
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fields2, "", sr) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = row[2]
        row[1] = row[3]

        cursor.updateRow(row)
```